# Eclipse oxygen 3 maven doesn't compile java files

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm new to Maven and I'm trying to create a basic Jersey  project with Eclipse Oxygen 3 IDE. For some reason when I run the compile or install goal, the target folder copy the java files, and indeed I don't see that Eclipse/Maven is creating any class file.

The Build/Clean options of Eclipse are disable, and using CTRL+B (compile shortcut) doesn't do anything.

The POM is as follows.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>MyName</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Any name</name>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>TargetName</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>/home/someuser/java/bin/javac</executable>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks for every help out there.

**Edit**

The project is created in Eclipse using "New" -> "Other" -> "Maven" -> "Maven project", and in the file system it doesn't contain a .project file.

Also I added the path of the compiler (see the edited pom.xml above), but the result is the same.

Comment: How did you create the actual project in Eclipse's workspace? Does it have a .project file, and if so, what are its contents?

Comment: First try it on plain command line...The given repository is not available....